# JWT não retorna o token ou objeto, node e react

Tags: node.js, react, cors, jwt

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma aplicação web utilizando node, react e js, ocorre que quando eu a fiz e testei no POSTMAN, tudo funcionou perfeitamente, porém, ao tentar fazer o deploy, não consigui fazer a  autenticação do usuário via jwt, ele retorna somente um objeto vazio.
De começo foi problema dos headers do cors, no entanto o solucionei, mas ainda não consigo receber o token  e demais informações do backend (API), embora, eu as consiga cadastrar os dados no Banco de Dados.
Diante disso, notei que o problema não está no envio dos dados pois eu consigo cadastrar no banco de dado, possivelmente está no jwt em alguma autorização que deixei passar ou código, pelo menos, acho.
Já procurei por inúmeros lugares e não encontrei a solução, existe alguma autorização a mais que permita o envio do token?

Servidor: KingHost

reposta no network = message Object { };

resposta no server = Rigth-hand side of "instaceof" is not function.

Segue o código do CORS para autorizar.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.meajudadireito.com.br');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Authorization,x-access-token');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Authorization,x-access-token');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-access-token'); //essta linha habilita o token no header
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  app.use(cors());
  next();
});
```

Código do controller users regisrer:

```
 static async register (req, res){
    const {name, email, cpf, password, confirmpassword} = req.body

   if(!name){
        res.status(422).json({ message: 'O nome Ã© obrigatÃ³rio!' })
        return
    }
    if (!email) {
        res.status(422).json({ message: 'O e-mail Ã© obrigatÃ³rio!' })
        return
      }
      if (!cpf) {
        res.status(422).json({ message: 'O CPF Ã© obrigatÃ³rio' })
        return
      } 
      const myCpf = process.env.CPF;
      if(cpf !== myCpf){
        res.status(422).json({ message: 'O CPF Ã© invÃ¡lido para usuÃ¡rio' })
        return
      } 
   if(!password){
    res.status(422).json({ message: 'A senha Ã© obrigatÃ³ria!' })
    return
   }   else if(password.length < 7 ){
    res.status(422).json({ message: 'A senha Ã© fraca!' })
    return
   }      
   if (!confirmpassword) {
    res.status(422).json({ message: 'A confirmaÃ§Ã£o de senha Ã© obrigatÃ³ria!' })
    return
  }
  if(password != confirmpassword){
  res.status(422).json({ message: 'A senha e a confirmaÃ§Ã£o de senha estÃ£o diferentes!' })
  return
  }
  const checkAmoutUser = await User.count({})
  if (checkAmoutUser === 1){
    res.status(422).json({ message: 'Limite de usuarios atigingido'})
  return
  }
 
  const checkIfUserExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } })
  if(checkIfUserExists){
    res.status(422).json({ message: 'E-mail jÃ¡ cadastrado' })
    return
  }
  
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(12)
  const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)

 const user = new User({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  cpf: cpf,
  password: hashedPassword,
})

try {
  const newUser = await user.save()

  await createUserToken(newUser, req, res)
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({ message: error })
}
}
```

Código do JWT

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
    require("dotenv").config();
    const secret = process.env.SECRET;

const createUserToken = async (user, req, res) => {
    const token = jwt.sign(
  
        {
          name: user.name,
          id: user.id,
        },
        secret
      );


   
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Você está autenticado!",
    token: token,
    userId: user.id,
  });
};

module.exports = createUserToken;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver, primeiro, alterei o modo como envie as requisições para o header, agora é assim:

```
    app.get('*', (req,res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization")
  res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-access-token"); //esta linha habilita o token no header
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  app.use(cors());
  next();
  });
```

E depois, achei a resposta nesse link, embora ele diga que não é a melhor saída, basicamente eu fiz um downgrade da versão 9 do jwt para a ^8.5.1.

Link para a resposta: [clique aqui](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/75019306/jwt-error-typeerror-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-an-object?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR&_x_tr_pto=sc)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

O jwt não parece ter problemas, você verificou se o seu objeto está sendo retornado corretamente nesse momento `await user.save()` ?

Outra observação é que não está utilizando o await  na função `jwt.sign` tente incluir o await

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado por responder, sim já tentei, o que estranhei é que no POSTMAN deu certo, uma hora li que eu deveria enviar as autorizações no header, então enviei tudo que é autorização, mas não deu certo, ele sempre retornar um * no header de resposta;  no chrome ele me manda um objeto vazio e o token como undefined, todabia outras requisições que são somente GET funcionam, por exemplo, testei listar categorias, então as adicionei direto no BC, e apareceu.